# Angular project Build successfully but giving these errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It shows me these errors after the project is run and build

```
style.d.ts(72,67): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,39): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(79,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(80,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Can anyone guide me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/831

Comment: @Vatsal Dashani try updating typescript to latest version

Comment: @Md.KhirulIslamOmi typescript  already updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install flax-layout again

```
npm uninstall @angular/flex-layout --save
```

than

```
 npm install @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0.15-beta --save
```

Answer (score 0):

execute in the terminal: tsc -v

At this time, the latest verstion would it be: 3.0.3

[image]

If not, you have a problem reference with your typescript version.